# How do I scale an angled bone on only two axes?

Tags: rigging, scale

How do i scale on only two axis a bone that is on a diagonal in view 3? Every time i try to scale with ctr alt s i get a longer bone as it were and pressing x/y/z scales the bone in the wrong direction since it is at an angle.
[image]

Comment: It seems like you want to scale a bone along its local axes, but it's not lined up with the global axes, so viewing it from the side in orthographic didn't help you. Is this right?

Comment: i think so. I do Shift D to create a new bone and  ctrl alt s to scale it but it gets scaled upwards , i dont want it 'clashing' with the parent bone. I added a pic. And i am also having trouble seeing through this duplicate bone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select pivot you do not want to move, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  *Snap Cursor to Selection* , press <kbd>.</kbd> (Period) key select *3D Cursor* the bone will then scale away from the 3D Cursor. Don't forget to press <kbd>.</kbd> (Period) and reset to *Median Point* afterwards.

[image]

To see through one bone to another you can toggle *Xray* in the top right hand corner of the viewport

This will put the bone in the right place, but it will not connect it. To do that, you might be better off not using duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> ), but rather using extrude (<kbd>E</kbd> ), which will branch out a new, connected, parented bone from whatever bone is selected.

I'm not sure what you want here, but if the 3D cursor way is what you need, remember to switch over to the bone tab in the properties editor and change the new bone's parent, probably also checking the box *Connected*.